# The Future builder in Flutter is fetching data twice

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

The Future builder in my Flutter app is fetching data twice, as opposed to fetching data just once.

```
class StudentListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StudentListView> createState() => _StudentListViewState();
}

class _StudentListViewState extends State<StudentListView> {

  List<StudentModel> students = [];

  late Future myFuture;

  Future<List<StudentModel>> getStudents() async {

    var response = await http.get(Uri.https(BASE_URL, APP_INTERSNSHIP_URL));

    var studentData = jsonDecode(response.body);

    for (var student in studentData) {

      final singlestudent = StudentModel(
          id: student["id"],
          name: student["name"]);
      students.add(singleStudent);
    }
    return students;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    myFuture = getstudents();
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getstudents();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          APP_TITLE,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: myFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: students.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(students[index].id.toString()),
                            Text(students[index].name.toString())
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ));
                });
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
          })
    );
  }
}
```

I've followed [various articles](https://flutter-examples.com/futurebuilder-is-called-multiple-times/), but nothing is working. Still after doing this, the app is fetching data twice.

P.S.: Is this is a standard way to fetching data in Flutter or is there something better?

P.S.S: All required libraries are added in the code, and the code doesn't have any errors. It is just fetching data twice.

Comment: just remove the getStudents() call from the build() method

Comment:  just found, thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getstudents(); <------ culprit, called it twice
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            APP_TITLE,
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: myFuture, <------ right place to call
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I guess you have already figured out, that you had called it twice,

To add on to it, you could directly use `getStudents` in the future, instead of setting it to the variable `myFuture`

```
body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getStudents(), // directly call it here
```

Remove the following lines

```
late Future myFuture;
```

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // myFuture = getstudents(); No more needed
    super.initState();
  }
```

And you can aswell define   `List<StudentModel> students = [];` inside the `getStudents()` as it is just used locally .